# FreePBX call forward from external phone

Tags: asterisk

I'm using freepbx 2.11 in our office.  If an employee is on the road, I want them to be able to setup call forwarding to their cell phone or other temporary number.  I have all the default feature codes setup and enabled, so to activate call forwarding it's *72.  This works fine from one of the phone extensions in the office, but how can I access this feature from an outside line.

When I configure the IVR entries, I have the option to set the destination to a feature code, but the call forward option is not in that list.  (Its enabled, but not an option in the IVR destination feature code list.)

What is the easiest way to allow a user to access a feature code using an outside line?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you configured an inbound route based on the callerID of the person travelling (their cell phone number) and routed those calls to a DISA and set the callerID in the DISA to their extension number then they could dial in and use the feature code(s) to enable or disable the CF.

You can set the *72 to something a little 'friendlier'.

Answer (score 0):

Your simplest solution may be to enable the 'follow me' feature for each user. They can then access the user portal in their web browser to configure the number they want to divert to. Using unfriendly '*' codes, it will not be the least of your problems just getting people to remember what to dial.